# Removing a SC Widget on Internet explorer 11

Tags: iframe, widget, soundcloud, internet-explorer-11

I have something like this.

```
<div class="player-wrapper"><iframe id="sc-palms" class="player-iframe" width="100%" height="120" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/164940733&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe></div>
```

I create a soundcloud widget:

```
iframe = document.getElementById('sc-palms')
player = SC.Widget(iframe)
```

I bind some click events to trigger the `toggle()` method. The user also has the ability to "skip" and load a new song. This song can be from somewhere other than soundcloud, so I need to completely remove the iframe and widget. I have no issues except on internet explorer. Currently I am removing the player by this code:

```
player = null;
$(".player-wrapper").html("");
```

If the soundcloud player is playing, then the iframe is removed the widget's sound is still playing in the background.  Any ideas about how to further kill this player in IE 11 would be greatly appreciated.  And please ask if you need any more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired behavior by setting the iframe's src attribute to an empty string. When I remove the player via:

```
$("player-wrapper iframe").attr("src","");
```

instead of

```
$("player-wrapper").html("");
```

The player stops playing.

I believe this may have something to do with internet explorer not allowing iframes to be removed when they have javascript events or listeners or something still tied to them. If I sound like I don't know exactly what I am talking about, it is because I don't.  If anyone wants to give a better answer or comment on this answer, I can update it with a better understanding. The reason I thought to try this method was because of these two links:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1777238

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4

The quote that got me thinking on these lines was this:

"In summary IE9 doesn't allow an iframe to be removed from the DOM if it will have javascript executed. This is to address a memory leak issue. IE9 will throw undefined property errors."

Sorry for adding some messiness to stackoverflow but if anyone can be helped by this answer, I'd like it to be out there. I've spent days trying to fix this.